# How to dynamically change CSS using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on complicated animation, I am trying to add effects by adding another class based on the val I am getting.

I have different css classes, and I wanna know how to dynamically add them this way.

```
.. Class="box bottom right"
```

when I add new class (eg: red).
It should be in my code this way:

```
.. Class="box bottom right red"
```

I am trying to change the css based on value I am calculating.

```
var els=2;

  function changeColor(els) {
    if (els>0) {
            $("box bottom right").addClass("red");
    } else{
            $("box bottom right").addClass("green");
    };

  }
```

Here is code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/BB6ED/1/

Comment: What calls your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.` to target elements by class as well as calling your function on page load:

```
var els=2;

  function changeColor(els) {
    if (els>0) {
            $(".box.bottom.right").addClass("red");
    } else{
            $(".box.bottom.right").addClass("green");
    };

  }

changeColor(els);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BB6ED/2/)**